# Make Google Canary appear on the Mac menu appearance as Google Canary and not as Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I use Google Chrome as my default browser and to debug I use Google Canary. This way I have a nice separation. Therefore a lot of times I have both browsers open at the same time. The only issue, which bugs me, is that both of them are named exactly the same on the top menu appearance bar in the apple IOS as you can see on the picture:

[image]

If you use Google Chrome it appears with exactly the same name which confuses me with my interaction between programs. Is there a way to personalise this name into Canary or Google Canary?

This way I will know in a simple view which browser I'm currently using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of the application menu is derived from the bundle name. The bundle name is the value of the `CFBundleName` key in the Info.plist file within the app bundle. You can edit this file and change the title of the application menu.

There's a slim chance that Chrome has been coded to be sensitive to the bundle name and that changing it will break it. For example, it may use its bundle name to construct file paths to its files (e.g. ~/Library/Application Support/<bundle name>).

Comment: Wow! I thought nobody would answer. I tried to search this file in my library but I just find a file called Google. So I'm guessing both applications use the same folder. I'm I searching in the correct place? I would like to tryout what you said and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: The Info.plist file is inside the app bundle. You have to right-click or Control-click on the app bundle icon in the Finder and select Show Package Contents. Then go into the Contents subfolder and you should see the Info.plist file. You have to edit it with a plain text editor or a program which understands property list files.

Comment: Yeeeep your right. It changes the name but then the program does not function anymore. Anyways thank you very much for the answer